# Optimal Time Series Weight for Quantile Estimation

Tags: optimization, regression, discrete-optimization

Given a time series, $x_1$, $x_2$, ..., $x_t$, .... I want to solve for
$$\mathrm{min}_{w_1, w_2, ..., w_m}\rho(x_t-\mathrm{Quantile}(q; x_{t-1}, x_{t-2}, ..., x_{t-m}; w_{t-1}, w_{t-2}, ..., w_{t-m}))\textrm{ for }q\in(0, 1)$$
Here, $\mathrm{Quantile}(q; x_{t-1}, x_{t-2}, ..., x_{t_m}; w_{t-1}, w_{t-2}, ..., w_{t-m})$ is the $q$-th quantile of samples, $x_{t-1}, x_{t-2}, ..., x_{t_m}$ with weights, $w_{t-1}, w_{t-2}, ..., w_{t-m}$. And $\rho(x)$ is defined to be
$$\rho(x)=q\cdot\mathrm{max}(x, 0)-(1-q)\cdot\mathrm{min}(x, 0)$$

Comment: Thanks for all hints and suggestions!!! Any help would be valued!!!

Comment: Even a proper tag or area of study would be very helpful to me:)

Comment: See this recent blog post: http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2021/06/median-quantiles-and-quantile.html

Comment: @RobPratt Thanks for that. The objective indeed comes from quantile regression. However, the above optimization predicts target by the quantile of weighted samples instead of a linear combination of these samples.